# How to find all options with repetition?

Tags: c

I'm looking at a problem I can't really still figure out.

I need all (now what's the right math term) permutations? tuples? combinations? with repetition made out of 4 given elements.

I've got the elements **A, B, C, D**. There is four of them, the amount is fixed. For a given *n*, I need to be able to get all possible options from these four elements. For example:

*n = 1*;
Possible options:
**A
B
C
D**

*n = 2*;
Possible options:
**AA
AB
AC
AD
BA
BB
BC
BD
...
DC
DD**

*n = 4*; Possible options: **AAAA
AAAB
AAAC
...
DDDC
DDDD**

Would anyone be able to kind of direct me somewhere? There are some following conditions, but I should be able to filter them on the go. Of course I tried searching for the answer, but no topics seem to be the same issue I'm trying to solve.

Big thanks to anyone who would at least try to pinch me in the right direction a bit.

Comment: What is the problem? How will *you* do this? I mean systematically with pen and paper.

Comment: Is this homework or a programmer test?

Comment: And the number growing exponentially with n is not a problem for you? For a set of k elements and a given n, there are k^n combinations.

Comment: There are many fun ways to implement it. Iterative - the least fun. Recursive - more fun. And using base-4.

Comment: Just for your info, those are called "strings of length *n* over the alphabet {A, B, C, D}". You may want to think of them as numbers from 0 to 4ⁿ − 1 represented in base 4 using the digits A for 0, B for 1, C for 2 and D for 3.

Comment: I think your first step is to figure out if this is a permutation or combination, and what tuples are.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it using nested loops because you need n for loops and n is not determined at first (and it is ridiculous to use n nested for loops). One approach to solving the problem is to use recursive functions. The recursive function should return the basic list consisting of 4 letters for n=1 and for n>1 it should call itself with parameter (n-1) and then append each one of the four letters to each returned string from the recursive call. I suggest you to try to implement it yourself before reading the following pseudo code!

```
list func(int n){
  if ( n == 1 ) {return list('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'); }
  else {
    result = list();
    permutations = func(n-1);
    for (each item in permutations) {
      result.append(item+'A');
      result.append(item+'B');
      result.append(item+'C');
      result.append(item+'D');
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```